# What is the meaning of branch-like icon next to breakpoint in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee, breakpoints

In Eclipse IDE for J2EE development, I'm seeing this new icon on my breakpoints. On all the breakpoints. Not sure why? And what does it mean? Could it be the reason my breakpoints arent working?

[image]

**Zooming in**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [Breakpoint Trigger Point](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-triggerpoint_option.htm) icon.

> All the other breakpoints that are initially suppressed by triggers will be hit only after any of the trigger points has been hit. All the triggers are disabled after a trigger point is hit and will be re-enabled after the run. Triggers will be rendered with an overlay of "T" and the breakpoints suppressed by the triggers will be rendered with an overlay of "T" with a cut.